# Create and deploy Webjob from another Webjob

Tags: azure, webjob

Is it possible to deploy a Webjob from another Webjob in Azure? I've read the documentation, it's all about manually instantiating a Webjob, or using CronJobs. I want, in a Webjob, deploy and run another Webjob with some parameters.

Comment: pretty sure it is, but quite "dirty". I don't think there is a native way to do that.

Comment: @4c74356b41Do you have more information on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to deploy a Webjob from another Webjob in Azure?

Yes, we could deploy a WebJob automatically also including WebJob way.
We could deploy a WebJob using [Kudu WebJob API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API).  I test it with fiddler,it works correctly. The following is my details steps.

```
https://{userName}:{password}@{WebAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/{continuous or triggered}/{job name}/
```

1.Get the username, password info from the azure website profile

[image]

2.Send the http put request with  header and attach the zip file in the request body

`Content-Type: application/zip`

`Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=myfilename`

[image]

3.Check from the azure portal that WebJob has been created correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was also the solution I've found!